# Could you tell me the purpose of these addresses in XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, port

Could you tell me the purpose of these addresses in XAMPP?

Although I try to launch `localhost: 8080 / login` my application springs boot but nothing displays in chrome.

[image]

Comment: The information is missing, check if your appache server in xampp listening on port 8080

Comment: oui il est par defaut sur le port 8080

Comment: Then check logs of appache in XAMPP,  there are two types of logs request logs and startup logs check both one where problem is being generated